# Line Break in PHP for-loop

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop

There have been a bunch of questions like this already, but none of the answers seem to help me. I would like to have a line-break after each output from a loop. I am using double-quoted strings, [like I read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238433/php-how-to-create-a-newline-character), as well as using HTML (because I want the browser to recognize the line-breaks too) [as I read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698078/how-do-i-start-a-new-html-line-from-php).

It does create a line-break, however only *below* the complete output.

I cannot manage to create a line-break *between* the outputs of the loop. Basically I get a block of text and then a linebreak.

**Here is the loop I am using:**

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$target_url = "http://www.buzzfeed.com/trending?country=en-us";
$html = new simple_html_dom();

$html->load_file($target_url);

$posts = $html->find('ul[class=list--numbered trending-posts trending-posts-    now]');
$limit = 10;
$limit = count($posts) < $limit ? count($posts) : $limit;
for($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++){
  $post = $posts[$i];
  $post->find('div[class=trending-post-text]',0)->outertext = "";
  echo strip_tags($post, '<p><a>') . "<br/>\n";
}
```

I've also tried `"\r\n"` and a bunch of variations, as well as the [nl2br() function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl2br.asp). I believe the PHP_EOL command is meant only for the command line, from what I've researched.

I'm an absolute beginner with PHP, so I am probably missing something simple, but I can't figure it out.

EDIT:
Here is what it prints:
http://globalsocialnews.com/crawler/test8.php

I also included the complete code in case that helps.

Comment: Can you show what it prints?

Comment: Can you paste the output somewhere?

Comment: *"It does create a line-break, however only below the complete output."* Put the `<br />` after the `}` that closes the `for` loop

Comment: You have an error in your code example: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/jasperko/public_html/globalsocialnews.com/crawler/test8.php on line 51`

Comment: sorry, I tried to implement the answer above you. gone now, didn't work for me

Comment: Did you try to write   echo "<br/>" or just "<br/>" after }  ?

Comment: I tried both and neither worked out. Ashish below had an answer which worked for me in the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do line break using css implementation ...
like:

```
.rcorners1 a {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;//for show extra margin between each line...  

    }
```

Edit: Use margin css attribute for extra margin...

please try implementing this...

Comment: this worked! is there also a way to add another linebreak to this?

Answer (score 1):

Better Use

```
echo "</br>";
```